# Trigger markdown processing via bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, showdown

Imagine a regular webpage where somebody wrote
[this *unprocessed* markdown](https://stackoverflow.com)...

Is there a bookmarklet that I can click such that it processes any raw markdown on the page?
It does not have to work everywhere, or accurately, just reasonably simple websites.

What I have tried so far:

```
javascript:(function(){
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
    .src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.7.2/showdown.min.js';
  var converter = new showdown.Converter();
  //and then?
})();`
```

But here I am already running into `ReferenceError: showdown is not defined`.

I have seen http://heckyesmarkdown.com but that does literally the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add a small timeout for the markdown library to load. Let's say, 3 seconds like so:

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
    .src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.7.2/showdown.min.js';

    setTimeout("var converter = new showdown.Converter(); alert(converter);", 3000);
})();
```